# Slf4j Logs not showing up on Docker container logs

Tags: spring-boot, docker, logging, docker-container

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot REST application on Docker. The application runs fine and the APIs are working as expected, but I don't see my application logs showing up on the container logs.

I haven't configured any log4j properties to append logs to a file. I don't see any file getting generated with logs.

Need some help here with capturing application logs on docker container logs.